# Loop issues in function

Tags: c

```
#define colsPerModule (uint8_t)32UL
#define boardArrayWidth (uint8_t)2UL
#define boardColWidth (colsPerModule*boardArrayWidth)

uint16_t padMsg(char *p)
{
    uint16_t i, x=strlen(p), c=boardColWidth/(*(DMD.fontPtr+3));
    if(boardColWidth%(*(DMD.fontPtr+3)))
        c+=1;
    for(i=0; i<c; i++,x++){
        *(p+x)=' ';
    }//user.msgRam
    *(p+x)='\0';
    return(strlen(p));
}
```

Pls could someone look at this code snippet and figure out what could be wrong. The variable `*(DMD.fontPtr+3)` has the value 9, as stored in the location it points to. Therefore, `c=boardColWidth/(*(DMD.fontPtr+3))` is  supposed to return the value 7, since  the constant `boardColWidth` equals 64 (32*2). But the expression  `boardColWidth/(*(DMD.fontPtr+3))` seems to rather return the value 2. It worked well if I manually assigned the value 7 to the variable c.

Comment: So just add `fprintf(stderr, "*(DMD.fontPtr+3)=%d\n", (int) *(DMD.fontPtr+3))` into the function to test whether your assumption "*The variable `*(DMD.fontPtr+3)` has the value 9*" is correct.

Comment: FYI, the `for` loop could be replaced with a call to `memset()`.

Comment: `memset(p+x, ' ', c);`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, @Barmar

Comment: A hot tip is to put at least some of the question (in this case maybe all), or some type of descriptive test BEFORE your code snippet. It might make it a lot more attractive for viewers in the feed, since it will show some background info even before opening the question, instead of a unformatted code gibberish (since the feed does not format the code).

Comment: I'm so sorry for the mistakes I made. I realized I initialized the pointer DMD.fontPtr to NULL. I'd not called the routine where I assigned it the target array before using it. So I was just messing up. Thanks so much for all your responses.

Comment: Everything's alright now. It's an embedded platform, so debugging wasn't as easy as in Windows. Thanks Everyone for your helpful contributions!

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings. (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`   I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu99` )

Comment: the integer division for the initial calculation of variable `c` will round down.  That is probably NOT what you really want to do.  Suggest adding the divisor -1 to the numerator so the rounding will be up

Comment: Thanks! I got it. I intended making use of only the integer part of the division, and take care of the remainder in another line (using %). The problem was that I was using a NULL pointer, wasn't pointing to a valid address. So the result was random. Thanks you all, once again.